# Not able to create Azure Scheduler with the existing storage account

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create an Azure scheduler with the Action type - Storage queue.  When I try to select the storage queue it says "No storage accounts found in the selected subscription and location" , whereas i had created the storage account for the UK region and confgiured the queue.

Please tell what kind of stroage of which location i need to select while creating the storage account for the scheduler.

Comment: What kind of storage account have you created?

Comment: locally redundant storage for queues.  using location north uk

Comment: Got the solution. Scheduler only supports Classic Storage , and classic storage is available outside UK [ West Europe ]

Comment: Awesome! Can you please put this as an answer? I think it will be helpful to others.

Comment: Absolutely ridiculous. Resorting to powershell - sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Azure Scheduler can post messages to either classic or new (ARM) Azure Storage account Queue, but the Azure portal only lists the classic Storage accounts for the selector.

[image]

Besides, [Azure REST API provide a way to create a new job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/scheduler/jobs/createorupdate), you can specify your new (ARM) storage account queue in job definition.

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell me how can i provide the ARM storage in my account queue job definition ?